# thinking sphinx scope yielding unexpected results from range input

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have an active record scope that I am attempting to duplicate in a sphinx_scope:

```
scope :active, -> (date) { where("DATE(?) BETWEEN active_date AND hide_date-1 ", date) } # between is inclusive
```

This is close enough for government work, unless someone could show me a better approach:

```
sphinx_scope(:search_active) { |today|
  {:with => {:active_date => 100.years.ago.to_i..today.to_s.to_time.to_i, :hide_date => today.to_s.to_time.to_i..100.years.from_now.to_i}
  }
```

(yes, today.to_s.to_time.to_i is a little awkward...)

My problem is that the results don't seem to be accurate.  For example, the query without the scope yields

```
sphinxQL> SELECT weight(),* FROM `standard_core` WHERE MATCH('1910.15') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 10 OPTION field_weights=(section_number=2); 
+----------+------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| weight() | id   | sphinx_deleted | sphinx_internal_id | active_date | hide_date | created_at | updated_at | sphinx_internal_class | title_sort                                                                        | section_number_sort |
+----------+------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|     8557 | 3633 |              0 |                908 |  1436936400 | 297642704 | 1451164539 | 1451164539 | Standard              | § 1910.15 Shipyard employment.                                                    | 1910.15             |
|     6549 | 3637 |              0 |                909 |  1436936400 | 297642704 | 1451164539 | 1451164539 | Standard              | § 1910.15(a) Adoption and extension of established safety and health...           | 1910.15(a)          |
|     6549 | 3641 |              0 |                910 |  1436936400 | 297642704 | 1451164539 | 1451164539 | Standard              | § 1910.15(b) Definitions. For purposes of this section:                           | 1910.15(b)          |
```

But with the scope, the most relevant results are missing:

```
sphinxQL> SELECT weight() as weight,* FROM `standard_core` WHERE MATCH('1910.15') AND `active_date` BETWEEN -1672108252 AND 1482127200 AND `hide_date` BETWEEN 1482127200 AND 4639325348 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 0, 10 OPTION field_weights=(section_number=2);
+--------+------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| weight | id   | sphinx_deleted | sphinx_internal_id | active_date | hide_date  | created_at | updated_at | sphinx_internal_class | title_sort                                                                        | section_number_sort |
+--------+------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|   4566 | 5469 |              0 |               1367 |  1436936400 | 1484632800 | 1451167759 | 1451167759 | Standard              | § 1910.27(d)(1)(vi) Ladder wells shall have a clear width of at least 15...       | 1910.27(d)(1)(vi)   |
|   4549 | 5413 |              0 |               1353 |  1436936400 | 1484632800 | 1451167757 | 1451167757 | Standard              | § 1910.27(c)(2) Ladders without cages or wells. A clear width of at least 15...   | 1910.27(c)(2)       |
|   4549 | 5453 |              0 |               1363 |  1436936400 | 1484632800 | 1451167758 | 1451167758 | Standard              | § 1910.27(d)(1)(ii) Cages or wells (except as provided in subparagraph (5) of...  | 1910.27(d)(1)(ii)   |
```

I don't think this is actually a thinking sphinx error, but rather something with sphinx itself.  Or, more likely... something I'm misunderstanding :p

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?

[edit] ---------------------------------------------------------

OK, with @DGM, I discovered that the values for hide_date are not correct in the sphinx database record. For the record id 3633, the mysql database record 908 has a date value of 2115-07-15.

```
'2115-07-15'.to_time.to_i
=> 4592610000
```

Clearly, there is a bit of discrepancy between `297642704` and `4592610000`.

So I'm either figuring the range incorrectly or the sphinx database is being populated with an error.

indices/standard_index.rb

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :standard, :with => :real_time do
  # fields
  indexes title, :sortable => true
  indexes content
  indexes section_number, :sortable => true

  # attributes
  has active_date, :type => :timestamp
  has hide_date,   :type => :timestamp
  has created_at,  :type => :timestamp
  has updated_at,  :type => :timestamp
end
```

Is this losing something in the translation between a mysql date field and a sphinx timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here, but some thoughts:

If you're storing those dates as string values, then that's what will be passed through to Sphinx. The `:type` settings are only used for generating the Sphinx configuration file, not for translating attribute values (though certainly, there's a strong argument they should do both!). Of course, that doesn't quite explain how 2115-07-15 becomes 297642704, but could be part of what's at play. Again, only if the model's returning `hide_date` as a String rather than a Date.

A separate issue is that Sphinx stores timestamps as unsigned integers, so anything before 1st Jan 1970 should be avoided.

Not a solution to the problem, but perhaps to the overarching problem: I would recommend using integer representations of the dates themselves in Sphinx. e.g. 2115-07-15 becomes 21150715.

So, something like the following in your model:

```
def hide_date_to_i
  hide_date.to_s.gsub('-', '').to_i
end
```

And then in the index definition:

```
has hide_date_to_i, :as => :hide_date, :type => :integer
```

You'll need to update your scope accordingly as well.

Hopefully that'll get things working accordingly, but if not, should at least make the Sphinx values easier to debug!

Comment: Nice workaround!  That makes it **so** much easier to troubleshoot.  I'm using a mysql `date` field, but I guess you're right it must be a string in the model. I'm rather amused because I try to avoid using dates as a string for sorting because it fails for most formats... yet it's part of the solution in this case.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that it's getting handled as a string somewhere, to be honest - both Rails and TS/Riddle should handle it as a Date instance. Still, does this mean things are working as expected now?

Comment: Converting it to an integer both works as expected and is easier to understand.  win-win.  Not sure what went hinky, but this works well :)

Answer (score 0):

Your hide_date data appears to be too low compared to the other time ranges:  297642704

Comment: Indeed you are correct.  Thanks for the eyeballs.  Hoping Pat sees this and addresses whether I'm figuring the time incorrectly or the sphinx database is populating incorrectly.